# Does Jetty have a http.nonProxyHosts variable?

Tags: jetty, http-proxy

I have configured Jetty as follows.

```
# ps aux | more
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
jetty        1  7.0  9.8 9931680 2421304 ?     Ssl  12:20   4:31 java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/jetty -server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dhttp.proxyHost=XXX -Dhttp.proxyPort=XXX -Dhttps.proxyHost=XXX -Dhttps.proxyPort=XXX -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost\|127.*\|[::1]\|10.*\|172.16.*\|172.17.*\|172.18.*\|172.19.*\|172.20.*\|172.21.*\|172.22.*\|172.23.*\|XXX -Xms1g -Xmx3g -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=XXX -jar /usr/local/jetty/start.jar
```

I have the feeling that the no-proxy variable (`http.nonProxyHosts`) is not read out and the HTTP connect proxy is always used.

Since I cannot change a third-party software so easily myself, I wonder how I call some/certain local resources. I can only change config. How?

Answer (score 1):

The [JVM system properties for controlling URL networking](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) in your command line ...

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=XXX 
-Dhttp.proxyPort=XXX 
-Dhttps.proxyHost=XXX 
-Dhttps.proxyPort=XXX 
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost\|127.*\|[::1]\|10.*\|172.16.*\|172.17.*\|172.18.*\|172.19.*\|172.20.*\|172.21.*\|172.22.*\|172.23.*\|XXX
```

... exist for outgoing connections made by any component in your JVM that uses the JVM specific HTTP Client behaviors.

In other words, the built in classes in the JVM.

- `java.net.HttpURLConnection` (if using `java.net.URL` originated connections)
- `java.net.http.HttpClient` (if you are using Java 9+)

If you are using an HTTP Client that doesn't use one of the 2 above classes, support for these system properties is vanishingly small.

Jetty's own `org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient` intentionally does not support the JVM system properties (as they cast far too wide of a net for practical use)

Many REST libraries also have dedicated HTTP Clients that don't use the JVM URL based HTTP connections, and also do not support these system properties.

Jetty Server itself does not have or use these concepts for incoming connections to the Jetty Server.

These concepts only exist for outgoing connections.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found out that the backslashes "\" are too much. After I removed them and only pipes "|" are left in the nonProxyHosts variable, everything works. :)